# Apache CXF | Multiple responses to a webservice call

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

We want to implement a webservice with CXF in such a way that the call to it is asynchronous and the server sends back multiple responses.  Is there a way in CXF or any other webservice API to do this or do we need to write our own custom implementation for this?

Answer (score 0):

That seems an unusual requirement.  Could you elaborate on the use case?  There may be a more appropriate mechanism to accomplish response delivery.

Answer (score 0):

If the result is really asynchronous and you can have the client listen for incoming messages, it's perhaps easiest to just use one-way messages in each direction.
But one alternative you could try instead is to deliver the results as an Atom stream, which you can take your time over producing. Be aware that I have not tried that out; I've just seen it described in the documentation (and didn't need it at the time). You might also need to switch to using a RESTful interaction style to make that work, but that's pretty easy with CXF.